# Algorithms for curve fitting with a given model

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Say I have a set of (x, y) data points, and I am told that the model that best describes these data points looks something like this:

[image: Equation]

Where A, B, C and D are unknown constants. The aim is to find values for A, B, C and D that create a '*function of best fit*', based on some measure of quality (e.g. [the coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)).

Many programs can take a series of data points and create a smooth best-fit function of different types (polynomial, exponential, etc). Their algorithms solve for coefficients in a given (simple) model, and most of these curve fitting algorithms are reasonably documented. However, the above function (meant to generally indicate a 'more complicated' function), cannot be fit to data without some custom programming.

My question is: What are some of the algorithms used for this kind of model fitting?

One algorithm that has been described to me is [Particle Swarm Optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization), which is quite computationally expensive. While I'm not suggesting there will be 'cheap' (in time complexity) algorithms for this sort of problem, I would be interested to know what other algorithms (evolutionary or otherwise) are out there.

Comment: Are you sure that equation is right? As written A, B, and C can all be lumped into a single coefficient, and `D^pi` is just a strange way to write a constant, so the equation reduces to `Mx - sin(Nx)`

Comment: @user3386109 It is not meant to be a specific equation (see paragraph 3) - you are correct though and I have edited it to better reflect the sort of relation I am describing.

Comment: Ok, that's a much more interesting equation, that defies all logic :) So I'll just throw [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) into the mix and be on my way. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I had to fit a function like yours using least squares, I would probably try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm. If you look at the Notes section of that page you can see that it amounts to approximating the function you are trying to fit with a linear function. The account there says that convergence is not guaranteed, which is true. Starting from a point x, it can step to a point x', which is even worse. However, if x is not a local optimum, there will be some point near x, Ax' + (1-A)x which is better, and you can try and find this by starting at A=1/2 and repeatedly halving it.

To minimize a completely unstructured mathematical function I would probably fall back on the Torczon Simplex algorithm, because there is a reasonably understandable proof that this converges under fairly weak assumptions. There is a pointer to this from the references at the end of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_search_%28optimization%29.